# select col value where another col is max or min

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, max, min

I have a table that looks like this:

```
user      timestamp1                     timestamp2
a         2020-10-07T15:36:01.323Z       2020-10-07T15:36:01.323Z
b         2020-10-07T15:36:01.323Z       2020-10-07T15:36:01.323Z
```

I can calculate the max or min time difference like this:

```
min((JULIANDAY(timestamp2) - JULIANDAY(timestamp1)) * 24) AS min
max((JULIANDAY(timestamp2) - JULIANDAY(timestamp1)) * 24) AS max
```

but how can I formulate an sql (sqlite) query such that I can extract the username + the min max value in a table?

The final result could look like this:

```
type    user     time
max     a        679..
min     b        12..
```

I tried something like this to just test:

```
"select user, ((JULIANDAY(timestamp2) - JULIANDAY(timestamp1)) * 24) AS val from mytable where ((JULIANDAY(timestamp2) - JULIANDAY(timestamp1)) * 24) == min((JULIANDAY(timestamp2) - JULIANDAY(timestamp1)) * 24)
```

I was hoping that this will return the username and the min value throughout, something like this:

```
user    val
a       12...
```

but I get an error that:

```
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) misuse of aggregate function min()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use `MIN()` and `MAX()` aggregate functions in 2 separate queries and `UNION ALL` for the results:

```
SELECT 'max' type, user, MAX((JULIANDAY(timestamp2) - JULIANDAY(timestamp1)) * 24) time FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT 'min' type, user, MIN((JULIANDAY(timestamp2) - JULIANDAY(timestamp1)) * 24) time FROM tablename
```

This query uses SQLite's feature of [bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query).

I would also suggest to use `strftime()` instead of `JULIANDAY()`, because it would provide better accuracy:

```
SELECT 'max' type, user, MAX((strftime('%s', timestamp2) - strftime('%s', timestamp1)) / 3600.0) time FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT 'min' type, user, MIN((strftime('%s', timestamp2) - strftime('%s', timestamp1)) / 3600.0) time FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=09b51e6818336df81690417d1ce88652).

Comment: can you explain why we use %s in the function. Which is the original unit and why we divide by 3600

Comment: @x89 `strftime('%s', some_timestamp)` returns the number of seconds passed since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' up to `some_timestamp`. The division by 3600 will return hours. You can find more here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html